universalRouter swapping tokens on uniswapV3
im building a simple router and i want to integrate the universal router, I'm able to make V2 swaps, but for some reason swapping tokens on a v3 pool the swap gets reverted
//if msg.value is not empty swap is ETH->tokens else tokens->eth
function swapV3(address token, uint256 amountIn) external payable {
        if(msg.value == 0 && amountIn == 0) revert("both amountIn and msg.value cant be zero");
        if(msg.value > 0 && amountIn > 0) revert("amountIn and msg.value both cant have value to swap");
        if(amountIn == 0){
    
            //commands params
            bytes memory swapCommand = abi.encodePacked(bytes1(uint8(Commands.V3_SWAP_EXACT_IN)));
            bytes memory wrapEthCommand = abi.encodePacked(bytes1(uint8(Commands.WRAP_ETH)));
            bytes memory commands = abi.encodePacked(wrapEthCommand,swapCommand);
            //calculate fee
            uint256 Fee =  msg.value * fee / 10000;
            uint256 amountMinFee = msg.value - Fee;
            //input params, arguments list for commands
            bytes[] memory inputs = new bytes[](2);
            inputs[0] = abi.encode(
                address(this),//reciever of the weth
                amountMinFee//amount of eth to wrapp
            );
            uint24 _fee = _findPool(address(weth),token);
            if(_fee == 0) revert();
            //build path
            bytes memory path = abi.encodePacked(address(weth),token,_fee);
            uint256 minAmountOut = 0;
            //build swap inputs
            inputs[1] = abi.encode(
                msg.sender,
                minAmountOut,
                amountMinFee,
                path,
                true
                );
            //call execute function
            uint256 deadline = block.timestamp+30;
            router.execute{value:amountMinFee}(commands,inputs,deadline);
        }
    }


this is the result when testing the swapV3 function
You can see the Execute function gets reverted but gets reverted after the swap function is executed. To my understanding, the swap function is the one on the pool contract.
this is what i use to build the params:
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/universal-router/technical-reference#v3_swap_exact_in
they don't mention the struct ExacInputParams in this documentation, wish is the way of setting up the params to swap on the swapRouter02

The path order of encoded arguments is wrong.
Place the fee between both tokens
bytes memory path = abi.encodePacked(address(weth),_fee, token);
Additionally in the case of a multihop swap the pattern continues
address public usdt = 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7;
address public weth = 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2;
address public pepe = 0x6982508145454ce325ddbe47a25d4ec3d2311933;
uint24 public usdtWethFee = 3000;
uint24 public pepeWethFee = 3000;

function encodeV3MultiHopPath() public view returns(bytes){
   return abi.encodePacked(usdt, usdtWethFee, weth, pepeWethFee, pepe)
}


thanks for the reply! hope you having an amazing holiday
ill try it out.
